# How do I navigator to a javascript function in eclipse?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery and I want to see `css()` function  source code, but I don't know how to navigator to it?  My IDE is eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse does not support this behavior at the moment. Some editors I know that do are Sublime Text 3, Visual Studio+ReSharper (2012 also without it), PHPStrom and WebStorm, unfortunately, none of those are free.

One solution would be to use the [jQuery viewer](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/) which makes going through [the jQuery source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js) easy.

Here is [`.css()`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.css)'s source code from the latest jQuery:

```
function (name, value) {
    return jQuery.access(this, function (elem, name, value) {
        var len, styles, map = {},
            i = 0;

        if (jQuery.isArray(name)) {
            styles = getStyles(elem);
            len = name.length;

            for (; i < len; i++) {
                map[name[i]] = jQuery.css(elem, name[i], false, styles);
            }

            return map;
        }

        return value !== undefined ? jQuery.style(elem, name, value) : jQuery.css(elem, name);
    },
    name, value, arguments.length > 1);
}
```

Comment: VS2012 can do this without Resharper, and Express is free.

Comment: @SLaks can you confirm that Express offers this? I don't have it installed at the moment.

Comment: @HiwayChe no problem, if this answer helped you solve your problem please consider accepting it. I've asked a bunch of my friends in the JavaScript chat room here in SO to edit in editors they use in case they offer support

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look of [jQuery source code here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src).